# Replacing String in Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am having an bit of trouble in replacing an string insde an .txt file with Batch

What i have now is this

```
:SetHostName

set /p HostName=Please Enter your hostname: 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set oldstring=%FTP_HOST%
set newstring=%HostName%

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FTPConfig.ini) do (
    set str=%%i
    set str=!str: %oldstring% = "hi"!
    echo !str!
)
```

But when i test it it wont replace the FTP_HOST instead it shows this

```
FTP_HOST=test
FTP_USER=hi
FTP_PASS=testing
FTP_PROGRAM_FOLDER=program
FTP_RESOURCE_FOLDER=resource

inside my .txt file i have this
FTP_HOST=test
FTP_USER=hi
FTP_PASS=testing
FTP_SERVER_FILE_LOCATION=program
FTP_SERVER_RESOURCE_LOCATION=resource
```

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this quite backwards.  This code appears to be trying to replace the actual text `FTP_HOST`, not the value that appears after it.  If you fixed the obvious errors, you'd have:

```
set oldstring=FTP_HOST
set newstring=%HostName%

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (FTPConfig.ini) do (
    set str=%%i
    set str=!str:%oldstring%=%newstring%!
    echo !str!
)
```

Assuming I enter `my.new.host`, that would give the output:

```
my.new.host=test
FTP_USER=hi
FTP_PASS=testing
FTP_PROGRAM_FOLDER=program
FTP_RESOURCE_FOLDER=resource
```

I really don't think that's what you intended.  What you probably wanted is something like this:

```
set oldstring=FTP_HOST
set newstring=%HostName%

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%i in (FTPConfig.ini) do (
    set str=%%j
    if "%%i"=="%oldstring%" set str=%newstring%
    echo %%i=!str!
)
```

Which yields:

```
FTP_HOST=my.new.host
FTP_USER=hi
FTP_PASS=testing
FTP_PROGRAM_FOLDER=program
FTP_RESOURCE_FOLDER=resource
```